How does postgresql sorting/string comparison work?
I have a program in c++ that queries from the sql database in asc order but when I do a string comparison function the values are not in asc order.
if I have three rows in a postgresql database enclosed in quotes.
"A A"
"AA"
"   "

Then I return them in asc order I get:
"   "
"AA"
"A A"

In my c++ code I have
for example:
std::string a1 = "   ";
std::string a2 = "AA";
std::string a3 = "A A";
std::cout<<a2.compare(a3)<<std::endl //returns 33 

as you can see it returns a positive value basically saying "AA">"A A" in value. This is contrary to sql return in ascending value because I would expect the opposite. If anyone has any idea on how the string comparison works for sql I would appreciate any information. Also, I know c++ does character by character comparison, but not sure how sql does it

The words you need to search against are "locale" and "collation": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/charset.html
